# @shopify/shopify-api jws dependence is not working

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm new in Shopify, I'm having a problem when I try to use the @shopify/shopify-api.
I'm importing this property from the API.

```
import Shopify from '@shopify/shopify-api'
```

When I do the import I get the next error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: util.inherits is not a function
at node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js (data-stream.js:39:6)
at __require (chunk-IGMYUX52.js?v=cd28f3b3:40:50)
at node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js (sign-stream.js:3:18)
at __require (chunk-IGMYUX52.js?v=cd28f3b3:40:50)
at node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jws/index.js (index.js:2:18)
at __require (chunk-IGMYUX52.js?v=cd28f3b3:40:50)
at node_modules/jsonwebtoken/decode.js (decode.js:1:11)
at __require (chunk-IGMYUX52.js?v=cd28f3b3:40:50)
at node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js (index.js:2:11)
at __require (chunk-IGMYUX52.js?v=cd28f3b3:40:50)
```

So I went to the line in the file where is happening the error:

```
node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js
```

[And I discovered that error is a property in a node package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Wp8.png)

if you can't see the image here the code line.

```
util.inherits(DataStream, Stream);
```

[So I went to the node documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovFlc.png) and I found that method is discouraged, but is not deprecated, therefore it should be working.

here is the description of the method if you can't see the image.

> Usage of `util.inherits()` is discouraged. Please use the ES6 class and extends keywords to get language level inheritance support. Also
> note that the two styles are semantically incompatible.
>
> Inherit the prototype methods from one constructor into another. The prototype of constructor will be set to a new object created from
> `superConstructor`.
>
> This mainly adds some input validation on top of `Object.setPrototypeOf(constructor.prototype, superConstructor.prototype)`. As an additional convenience,
> `superConstructor` will be accessible through the `constructor.super_`
> property.

The package in question is named jws, I'm not so sure the purpose of this package, I had the idea to modify the file and use prototypical inheritance replacing that code line but I don't know how good an idea it is do that. furthermore I would have to do that for each file that has that problem, i haven't found any information about this on the intenet.

Comment: What version of the Shopify package are you using ?